# Limiting creation Of Object in multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading, object, java-8, concurrency

In an interview the `question` was asked.

We have `10 thread` and we have `100 task`. Each task crate `Objects`. We have to limit the number of `Object creation` when resources are getting highly used. They asked

1. How will you identify because of so many `object getting created` so your resource are highly used.
2. How will you limit the `creation of object` when resources are highly used.
3. Since lot of `object getting created`, when they are becoming unused, `gc()` is also acting. and sometimes it throws error `gc used exceeded`.

I tried but could not answer properly. They rejected.

Could you guide me to think of the solution? I mean I am not even getting clue of it.

Comment: Company name I have changed, but the company was of same level or you can say bigger brand than amazon :)

Comment: Did [whatever company it was] ask you not to discuss things you heard during your interviews?

Comment: The company doesn't matter. And giving details like "bigger" only sounds like bragging and let us find which company it is. Either way it is not good for you.

Comment: The problem with questions like this is that the only one who can know the "correct" answer is the interviewer asking you it. What those interviewers usually want is to at least hear/see you think about the problem. eG: Maybe they would have been happy if you said the first step would be to go back to the drawing board and see if there isn't a better solution than creating thousands of temporary object only to have the GC immediately take care of them. Or maybe they would have hated that answer. The thing is we don't really know what their expectation of a good answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the objects that you create are of a specific class you can use a static variable inside that class to hold the number of created instances. You can use for example an AtomicInteger to hold the number of created instances so you don't need to manually synchronize the access to that variable.

You can limit the number of instances looking at that variable, you can do that before invoking the new operator or before calling it looking at the current value of the AtomicInteger

The code can be something similar to that:

```
 public MyClass {
     private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

     public MyClass() {
         if (counter.getAndIncrement() > 100000) {
             throw new RuntimeException("More than 100000 objects created");
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you Davide. but here we are limiting object with a particular number. not every time resources will be busy. Can we make it Dynamic. They suggested to use ThreadLocal. I dont know ThreadLocal  will help.

Comment: You can use a ThreadLocal (holding an Integer) instead of an AtomicInteger. In this case having a similar logic you can limit the number of created instances per thread instead of per JVM, but the problem is generally the memory size that is per JVM, not per thread this is the reason why I used an AtomicInteger instead of a ThreadLocal